# How does Maven's Aggregation Model comply with its Dependency Mechanism?

Tags: maven, inheritance, dependencies, aggregation

My question is relatively simple. I do have a project that has a typical parent pom with a dependency management and a module with a pom that "normaly" inherits those dependencies.

If I explicitly name the parent inside the inherited pom, then the project builds successfully, but if I omit the parent information then the project fails to build.

One would expect maven to be able to build this project normally since the aggregation pom lists all the modules along with the dependency management.

Why is that not the case?

Answer (score 5):

Because you are mixing *inheritance* with *aggregation*.

In Maven, [inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) means declaring a parent POM for this POM (with the `<parent>` tag element). By default, each POM inherits from the Super POM. This inheritance allows to factor out common dependencies inside the parent (like plugins version or dependency management).

On the other hand, [aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) is a synonym for a multi-module project. This means that an aggregator project declares sub-modules (with the `<module>` tag element).

Even if it's not commonly used, you could have a project that aggregates sub-modules for which their parent is not this project. It is very common to see parent projects that are also aggregator project but it's not a necessity. So the build fails in your case because you reached the situation of an aggregator project that is not a parent project anymore so the sub-modules do not inherit from its configuration.

Quoting from the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance_v):

> A POM project may be inherited from - but does not necessarily have - any modules that it aggregates. Conversely, a POM project may aggregate projects that do not inherit from it.

---

Further reading:

- The Maven book: [Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit) (selected quote):

  > There is a difference between inheriting from a parent project and being managed by a multimodule project. A parent project is one that passes its values to its children. A multimodule project simply manages a group of other subprojects or modules. The multimodule relationship is defined from the topmost level downwards. When setting up a multimodule project, you are simply telling a project that its build should include the specified modules. Multimodule builds are to be used to group modules together in a single build. The parent-child relationship is defined from the leaf node upwards. The parent-child relationship deals more with the definition of a particular project. When you associate a child with its parent, you are telling Maven that a project’s POM is derived from another.
- Maven documentaton: [Project Inheritance vs Project Aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance_vs_Project_Aggregation) (selected quote):

  > If you have several Maven projects, and they all have similar configurations, you can refactor your projects by pulling out those similar configurations and making a parent project. Thus, all you have to do is to let your Maven projects inherit that parent project, and those configurations would then be applied to all of them.
  >
  > And if you have a group of projects that are built or processed together, you can create a parent project and have that parent project declare those projects as its modules. By doing so, you'd only have to build the parent and the rest will follow.